# endnotes.sty inserts unwanted text into fancy headers

Tags: fancyhdr, endnotes

I have a document that uses `fancyhdr` (with `fancy` page style enabled), and also uses `endnotes.sty` to create endnotes. However, the pages that have endnotes on get the text "Notes" inserted into the header, which I do not want (the header should contain only a banner graphic).  I can not find any hint in the `endnotes.sty` as to how to suppress this text in the header, can anyone advise?

Here is a simple `tex` script that generates the undesired behaviour as an example:

```
    %% LyX 2.1.1 created this file.
\documentclass[english]{extarticle}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm,headheight=1cm,headsep=1cm,footskip=1cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatother
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\title{\textcolor{blue}{Endnotes create unwanted text in the header of the
last page}}
\author{A.N. Other}
\maketitle
\subsection*{\lipsum[2]}
\lipsum[2-4]\endnote{This is an endnote}
\lipsum[5-10]
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`endnotes.sty` has

```
\def\enoteheading{\section*{\notesname
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{\notesname}}{\MakeUppercase{\notesname}}}%
  \mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip}
```

which updated the marks for the header. You can redefine this to something like

```
\renewcommand\enoteheading{\section*{\notesname}\mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[english]{extarticle}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm,headheight=1cm,headsep=1cm,footskip=1cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatother
\usepackage{babel}

\renewcommand\enoteheading{\section*{\notesname}\mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\title{\textcolor{blue}{Endnotes create unwanted text in the header of the
last page}}
\author{A.N. Other}
\maketitle
\subsection*{\lipsum[2]}
\lipsum[2-4]\endnote{This is an endnote}
\lipsum[5-10]
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

The resulting document:

[image]

Comment: Thanks - a perfect answer in less than 10 minutes after posting the question. Awesome! (upvoted this answer, but it won't show until I get enough rep)